# Why POST request doesn't work in iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, axios

This code perfectly works in all desktop browsers including Safari, but doesn't work in iOS Safari. I simply couldnt login to the website. Here is the code sample:

```
async LOGIN_USER ({commit}, {username, password}) {
  this.dispatch('CLEAR_ERROR')
  this.dispatch('SET_LOADING', true)
  var bodyFormData = new FormData()
  bodyFormData.append('username', username)
  bodyFormData.append('password', password)
  await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: MAINURL + '/auth/jwt/create/',
    config: {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    },
    data: bodyFormData
  })
```

A week of internet research didn't give anything. Please help.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Anything which might hint at the problem?

Comment: ^^ for instance, does the promise from the `async` function reject? You should have an error handler on the call to `LOGIN_USER` (or whatever that call returns its promise to) that can report the rejection to you. What do you see when you debug this? (Which is a pain and effectively requires having a Mac [last I checked the \*nix options were unreliable], but if you're targeting iOS, sometimes you need to be able to debug iOS devices.)

Comment: How did you test this code in browser? Is the server running on localhost? Because when running on iOS device, you may encounter CORS issue if the server does not allow CORS request.

Comment: Try removing content-type because you are not sending any image.

Comment: @Mathyn No errors in iOS Safari browser console. I have put alerts in different parts of the code, its running up until this line: bodyFormData.append('username', username)

Comment: @Juky I tested on remote server as well, same issue.

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi I've tried. No effect unfortunately

Comment: @Marcel could you try adding a simple try catch around the body of the function and log any exceptions which might be thrown. Code suddenly stopping at some point seems to suggest an exception is being thrown.

Comment: @Mathyn I think I have found the root of this problem. It is all about await operator. I suppose Mobile Safari does not support that. I simply delete it and the server finally responded. So, could you suggest any workaround which still will allow me to use async/await instead of .then?

Comment: I posted a possible solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by the user in the comments the problem is causes by the browser not supporting the async/await feature. This can happen on iOS version lower than 10.3 as shown [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions).

Since this is keyword and not a function it cannot be easily fixed by including a polyfill script. Other methods do exist however.

One tool you can use is [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Babel is a compiler which takes modern ES7 Javascript and turns it into something older browsers can also support.

[These docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator) describe how to configure Babel to turn async/await into backwards compatible code.

At the very least the steps involved would look like this:

Install the Babel packages:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env
npm install --save @babel/polyfill
```

Install the plugin to turn async/await into generators

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator
```

From the command line run

```
babel --plugins @babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator script.js
```

Where `script.js` is your Javascript file containing the HTTP request.

This is just a general overview of the steps involved. The precise steps will be dependent on how you have set up your project. Still, in general, the steps will be similar.